# Excessive Heat Coming From Video Transmitter and Motor Electronic Boards

Tags: quadcopter, motor, electronics

I'm building a quadcopter and I'm finding that certain electronic boards are heating up beyond what I believe the heat should be.

In this case I hooked up the video transmitter and then tested it. The board gets extremely hot. **Is this normal?**

I also noticed the electronic boards for the motors seem excessively hot as well.

Everything else seems to be either cool or warm to the touch, but nothing like the two afore mentioned electronic boards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All boards come with data-sheets which should list the temperature range of operation for the given board.

Several video transmitter can become quite hot, thus it is recommend to have them into airflow even in static testing. Aggravating factors might be bad antenna, or non optimal power voltage.

Concerning the other board it's unclear if you are speaking of a power splitter or the ESCs.

Comment: I looked it up and this is what it said... -10 +85 C... Is that correct. 85 Celsius? That means it can be a hot as 185* Fahrenheit. Doesn't that seem outlandish?

Comment: 85 Celsius makes sense to my for many electronic components  ( I have no clue about Farenheit). Bear in mind that only operating at this temperature will impact the lifetime of your component, but the component is guarantied to work. You can try to keep the component in airflow and put some aluminum heatsinks.